# An element of type 'library' with ID 'some-id' could not be found

Tags: java, eclipse, jndi, websphere-liberty

I want to get some properties out of my program, and I have to do it with `JNDI` (some attributes were setted there by me), using `WAS Liberty`. But when I use these tags:

```
<jndiObjectFactory id="id-factory" className="some-class" objectClassName="another-class" libraryRef="name-of-lib" />
```

on `server.xml`, `Eclipse` shows me a warning that says:

```
An element of type 'library' with ID 'name-of-lib' could not be found
```

I get these classes (`some-class` and `another-class`) with a `dependency` on `pom.xml`.

I went inside these classes, but I didn't find something like `name-of-lib`

There is another way to find out if `name-of-lib` is really inside these classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure a `<library>` element in your server.xml, give it an ID, and make the ID of your `<library>` the value of the libraryRef.

Suppose you have the library `foo.jar` located at `/temp/myLibs/foo.jar` on your file system, you could configure this library in your server.xml like this:

```
<jndiObjectFactory ... libraryRef="MyLib"/>

<library id="MyLib">
  <fileset dir="/temp/myLibs" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>
```

Or instead of using a `libraryRef` to point to the ID of your `<library>` you could nest the `<library>` under your `<jndiObjectFactory>` like this:

```
<jndiObjectFactory ...>
  <library>
    <fileset dir="/temp/myLibs" includes="*.jar"/>
  </library>
</jndiObjectFactory>
```

Here is the [IBM Doc for shared library configuration](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html).

Comment: Thanks! Later, I found these links (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_3p_apis.html) and (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jndi_refentry.html) that also helped me to solve this problem.